# Recommendation needed from Solana/developer

Tags: developer

I'd love a beginner to advance course from the array of courses on the solana/developer site. The course should be a latest one so it doesn't bug one down with outdated codes. Thank you.

Comment: Checkout https://www.soldev.app/course it's great for a beginners.

Comment: Have a look at a compilation of Solana resources: https://solana.com/developers